# Using Entity Framework with multiple servers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web-config

Just cutting my teeth with Entity Framework for ASP.NET MVC, and getting to the stage where we need to think about testing and deploying our first app. So far, I have simply defined the **DbContext** as a hard-coded SQL Server connection string, but with several model entities defined it becomes painful to switch between our production and test DB servers.

Normally, when we have been writing our own Data Access Layer, we define something like this in the `Web.Staging.config` or `Web.Release.config` files to allow for easy switching:

```
<add key="DBIP" value="x.y.z.z" /> <!-- Local Debug -->
```

Then, when we build up the connection string, we can just refer to whatever the configured value is. Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be a way to "globally" set such a parameter, meaning that we have to maintain dozens of EF connection strings each time. There are always going to be concessions like this where generated code is concerned, but I'm interested to see if anyone has arrived at a labour-saving workaround.

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why don't you use the connection strings section in web.config? What do you mean by "globally" setting parameters? I don't see how three environments (dev, test, prod) require "dozens" of connection strings.

Comment: When you define a new EDMX for each particular model, for example Person.edmx, Product.edmx, they all have separate connection strings called "PersonEntities", etc.

Ideally, there would be a "base" connection string that everything refers back to...

Comment: An EDMX for each particular model? You're not having one EDMX for each entity I hope? How many have you got?

Comment: Like I said, one for each model. Are you saying the best solution is a monolithic approach? We have a LOT of objects to model...

Comment: Well, you can have several aggregates, but an EDMX per class is not the way to work with EF.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection strings SHOULD be held within your web config, each environment will have it's own config like you've stated `Web.Staing.config`, `Web.Release.Config`

You can pass the name of your connection string to the `DbContext`.  Keep the name the same in all environments and you won't have a problem.

**Example**

```
public class BaconContext : DbContext
{
    public BaconContext()
        : base("BaconDatabase")
    {
    }
}

<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BaconDatabase"
     connectionString="Data Source=localhost"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I agree that they should be held there, my question relates to when you want to change the reference to the DB server. Basically, it seems like you just have to maintain a number of web.config files to cover each of these systems.